# Converting my Automator workflow to AppleScript app?

Tags: applescript, catalina, automator

I've configured this Automator workflow that I would like to convert to an AppleScript app:
[image]

So far I've come up with this AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke command using command down
    keystroke tab using command down
    keystroke "q" using command down
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    activate
end tell

tell application "SoundSource"
    activate
end tell

tell application "BetterTouchTool"
    activate
end tell

tell application "Finder" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "q" using command down
    return input
end tell
```

end run

Additional info:

The first item (Command, Tab, Command Q) is to Quit an app called "UAD Meter & Control Panel". This app launches upon startup automatically and this seems to be hard wired behavior, there's no preference to turn it off. The app itself is greyed out every time I tried to add it into the Automator workflow. The only way to quit the app is via the Application Switcher and then hitting Command Q.

The last item in the sequence is to Quit Finder because I don't like having the Finder in the Application Switcher.

The problem is this AppleScript completely stops working after launching Safari for some reason while the Automator workflow works flawlessly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check to see if UAD is in your Login Items? System Prefs > User & Groups > Your Name > login Items (& incidentally, why not put the apps you do want to launch in there?)

Comment: There are only 2 items in my Login Items: UA Mixer Engine and UAD Meter Launcher, so no  UAD Meter & Control Panel there. In the past I've experimented with removing those 2 items from Login Items but it caused several errors...

Comment: @Tetsujin and to answer your second question, the reason is because there are times when I don't want these apps to launch upon startup.