# AppleScript app runs in a loop

Tags: applescript, catalina

I have this AppleScript to quit all apps and then shut down:

```
tell application "System Events" to set quitapps to name of every application process whose visible is true and name is not "Finder"
repeat with closeall in quitapps
    quit application closeall
end repeat

tell application "Finder"
    shut down
end tell

return input
end run
```

Problem is when I restart after shutting down with this app the computer keeps shutting down in a loop. I had to start in Safe Mode, delete the AppleScript app I made, shut down and log back in normally to fix the problem. Obviously there's something wrong with my script which is causing the loop but I don't know what it is, need help!

Comment: Why do you want to close all your applications before shutdown in the first place? The OS does this anyway already.

Comment: Combined with https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413417/converting-my-automator-workflow-to-applescript-app this seems a whole lot of unnecessary manual start/stop. Can you explain why you need to do all this?

Comment: @nohillside Oh ok so I can just use "tell application "Finder", shut down, end tell" and omit the stuff before that?

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not sure what you mean by "start and stop" but to be honest I'm really not well versed in all of this... I'm kind of just copying and pasting little snippets and hoping they work.

Comment: You just seem to be trying to micro-manage the Mac, without telling us your reasoning. This makes people suspect an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) This one, especially, is a single key command anyway, no script needed. https://support.apple.com/HT201236

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah I can't use the default key command to Shut Down because I've remapped my Eject key to a different key using Karabiner Elements. What I'm actually trying to achieve is to be able to open up Spotlight, type in "shut down" and hit Return to trigger that Apple Script app to shut down the computer. Of course I could go to the Menu Bar and click on Shut Down but I'd really like to use the Spotlight AppleScript method.

Comment: Then all you need to do is in **Script Editor** save a single line of _code_ `tell application "Finder" to shut down` as an _application_ named **Shut Down**.

Comment: You still have 2 quicker alternatives. 1. Use the  menu 2. Set a key command. I use cmd/ctrl/shift/opt/S (which makes it easy to do intentionally, even one-handed, but unlikely to happen accidentally)

Comment: @ user3439894 I tried editing it to tell application "Finder" to shut down, resaved the app, tried it out and got the Shut Down loop again. Had to boot into Safe Mode, delete the app once again, restart and log back in normally again. I'm really not sure why it does that looping thing. Is it because I don't have Finder running in the background like it normally is/does? I actually made an Automator app that "Quits All Applications" and then runs "tell application "Finder"
    shut down
end tell" which worked fine. It's only when I tried converting it to an AppleScript app that I got the loop

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah it's looking more and more like I have to just set a key command for this.

Comment: Yes. I noticed from your other question that you were trying to quit Finder. Another micro-management that worries me. What are you hoping to gain?

Comment: @Tetsujin Because I use the Command Tab App Switcher a lot but the Finder in there gets in the way. You can only remove Finder from the App Switcher by quitting the app entirely. Unless you know a better way that doesn't involve installing a third party app. It's pretty petty stuff I know.

Comment: Ah, yes. Lots of people seem addicted to that switcher. Personally, I never use it. I have much better methods of getting to where I need to be, using Spaces.

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: @user3439894 Catalina, latest version